# react-hook-form: using readyOnly in a select element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I am trying to use readOnly in a select element so the user is unable to change the value of the input field but when submiting the form I still need that value for the Api and I heard that the only way to do that in react-hook-form is to use readOnly instead of disabled, it worked in a normal input field but typescript gives an error in select element.
This is the code:

```js
interface dataProps {
  field_id: any;
  disabled: boolean;
}
```

```
<select
  readOnly={props.disabled}
  id={props.field_id}
  {...register(...)}
  defaultValue={...}
  onChange={...}
  >
  <option>
    {...}
  </option>
  renderList(...)
</select>
```

I tried to shorten the code as much as possible, this is the whole error I get:

```
Type '{ children: any[]; defaultValue: any; onChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void; onBlur: ChangeHandler; ref: RefCallBack; name: string; readOnly: true; id: any; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>, HTMLSelectElement>'.
  Property 'readOnly' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>, HTMLSelectElement>'.
```

I read documentation of react-hook-form but I didn't see anything there about using `readOnly`, I landed on [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-disabled-inputs-oihxx?file=/src/App.tsx) link and when I tried to change the input there that has `readOnly` to select it gives the same error, is there a way to make that `readOnly` work or there is a workaround to make disabled save the data inside the `handleSubmit`?

Comment: Read only isn't supported in select see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/readonly. This isn't a react hook form issue it's typescript enforcing HTML spec

Comment: So can you suggest how I can deal with the problem, is there a way to use disabled and still save the values in react hook form

Comment: How about, in case of `props.disabled===true`, displaying the data just as a simple text node (or disabled text input) instead of the select element? And for the purpose of passing the value to the API, using `<input type="hidden" id="{props.field_id}" value={value}>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `disabled` attribute doesn't remove the field in `react-hook-form` when submitting. If you don't allow the user to edit the value, you can use it:

```
// category field is still registered even when set disabled.
<select {...register("category")} disabled>
```

In case you want to really remove the field from the submitted value, set `disabled` when calling `register` using RHF own API:

```
<input {...register("firstName", { disabled: true })}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: With my team we decided to just configure the api so it takes only the fields that are not disabled which makes sense, but your answer seems to be working the way I wanted, so I will mark is as solution, thank you!